# Global var confusion: var a vs window.a

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I used to think that when you declare a variable in the global namespace, in the context of a web browser it becomes attached to the window object. This does seem to happen, but there must be a difference between declaring a global variable with the `var` keyword and attaching it directly to the window object. See this from the Chrome console:

```
var a;
> undefined
window.hasOwnProperty("a")
> true
window.a = 0
> 0
delete window.a
> false
window.hasOwnProperty("a")
> true
/* so it's still there */
window.a
> 0

window.b = undefined
> undefined
window.hasOwnProperty("b")
> true
window.b = 0
> 0
delete window.b
> true
window.hasOwnProperty("b")
> false
window.b
> undefined
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: You'll want to use `"a"` and `"b"` instead of `a` and `b` in the `hasOwnProperty` calls!

Comment: Thanks, will edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've identified the only significant difference: If you use `var`, you can't `delete` the property that gets created on the global object. If you don't, if you just assign to a property to create it, then like all object properties you can delete it.

It seems a bit arbitrary, but really it makes sense: You can't remove the `var` statement at runtime, after all, and the semantics are that `var` creates a property on the current execution context's variable environment's binding object. *(Whew, that was a mouthful.)* And so it makes sense that it creates a non-deletable property.

The details are in [§10.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5) and [§10.2.1.1.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1.1.2) of the specification. §10.5 basically says that `var` triggers CreateMutableBinding (§10.2.1.1.2) with the D argument being false (false = not deletable).

Comment: This sums up what I found out, yes. It does not explain why it works like that, though.

Comment: @connexo: That's just how it works. Why wouldn't it? And imo it makes sense that you cannot "undeclare" `var`iables.

Comment: @connexo - because `delete` removes properties from objects.  It doesn't remove variables.  So, they made it so that it works to remove a  property on the `window` object, but not if you declare it with `var`.   So, there's some logic for it, but why they chose that logic is only known by the one who originally decided it.

Comment: @connexo: I've expanded and cited the relevant parts of the spec if you want to dive into it deeper. :-)

Comment: So there's a difference between a variable and an object property?

Comment: @connexo: Yes and no. The global environment is the only one where you can *see* that variables are really properties of an object. Local variables in functions are also specified to be properties of an object (the "binding object" of the current "variable environment"), but since there's no way to programmatically access that binding object, it's not something you can really see in code. What's special about the global environment is that the binding object is the global object, and you can access the global object (as `this` at global scope, or through its `window` property [on browsers]).

Comment: @connexo: Sorry for all the terminology there, but when you start getting into the mechanics of how this stuff works under the hood, it's a bit unavoidable. :-) The glossing-over version is: Every context (the global context, or the context created when you call a function) has an object it holds variables in as properties. The global one is also the global object. The one in a function call isn't, and is inaccessible (you can only access its properties, which are the local variables and a few other things). All `var` does is say "Create a property on that object, but make it non-deletable."

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanations which really helped me understand the *what*. Yet there still is a big questionmark next to the *why*.

Comment: @connexo - see this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/1nmocheg/.  The `configurable` attribute is different on the property depending upon how it is declared.

Comment: @connexo: Re "why": As I said in the answer and Bergi and jfriend00 said in comments: Because It doesn't make sense to "undeclare" a variable. That's the "why." If you want more than that, you'll have to ask Brendan Eich -- but I suspect he'll just say the same thing. :-)